# How do I use super-sed's Perl regex dot match?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to use [super-sed](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/ssed/)'s Perl regex /S, but can't get it to work at all. This flag makes dots match newlines. This would be a very handy tool, if only I could understand how it's used! For example, I expect the following command will match and replace the pattern which spans across a newline to be replaced with Xs:

```
echo "(123) 456-7890\n(212) 567-9050" | ssed -R -e "s/78.*?5/x/S"
```

So, I am expecting this output:

```
(123) 456-XXXX
XXXXXXX67-9050
```

Instead I get (no match):

```
(123) 456-7890
(212) 567-9050
```

Comment: How to identify the pattern? `n` characters after `78`? to get the `regEx`

Comment: Which version of sed, which shell and version do you use?

Comment: Why does the expected  output stop at the second 5 in line two and not at the last 5. eg. why not `xxxxxxxxxxxx50` in the last line?

Comment: I think you need a RE that replaces each character individually as you dont have a "create as much `x`" as the length of the match was"-functionality. The RE will look messy and some if/then/else/for construct will probably look much cleaner.

Comment: @Inian, you've edited my question incorrectly:  I am specifically talking about ssed (not sed). ssed or super-sed has perl's 5 regex built in with the -R flag.

Comment: @Cyrus: ssed --version
super-sed version 3.62
based on GNU sed version 4.1

Comment: @gregory : my bad! Hope it's fixed now

Comment: @gregory Can you explain why the expected output stops replacing at the second `5` in the second line and not at the last `5`? In other words: what are the precise requirements for the replacement? I have a gnu sed of about 30 bytes that (at the moment) replaces up to the last `5` in the second line.

Comment: @LarsFischer: The regex uses a non-greedy `.*?` to indicate that it should stop at the first, not last, opportunity.  It's a standard feature of Perl regexes.

Comment: @LarsFischer: I'm not sure; I don't understand exactly what the question's up to. However, the `.*?` notation is a non-greedy match, and my 'first, not last' characterization is very crude and casual. I think that the expected output is not obtainable via the regex used, even assuming you fix the replacement material and work across the newline. It should stop X'ing at the 5 in `(456)` on the second line, not the 5 of the `567` on the second line. So there is confusion — either on my part or on the OP's part. My best guess is "oversight by the OP; didn't notice the first 5 on the second line"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your insight. I also believe the the RE would match only up to the first `5`.

Comment: @gregory Sorry, I just realized that you are especially interested in super sed. I had something in mind for gnu sed and its `-z` option, that will probably not work in ssed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ssed, like sed, works in a line-based manner. If you want to work on multiple lines at the same time, you have to fetch them first. One way to do that in sed (and ssed) is

```
:a $! { N; ba; }
```

Where `:a` is a jump label, `N` fetches the next line, `ba` jumps back to `:a` and the `$!` check sees to it that this only happens as long as there are more lines to read.

Once we have that, the other difficulty is to get the right number of `X`s into the right places. Ssed, like sed, does not make this very convenient, and it requires some shuffling around with the hold buffer to get the substituted part isolated and ready for processing. I came up with the following:

```
$ ssed -R ':a $! { N; ba; }; h; s/(.*?78)(.*?5)(.*)/\2/S; s/./X/g; s/^/@/; x; G; s/(.*?78)(.*?5)(.*)\n@(.*)/\1\4\3/S' << EOF
> (123) 456-7890
> (212) 567-9050
> EOF
(123) 456-78XX
XXXXXXX67-9050
```

This works as follows:

```
:a $! { N; ba; }                     # read full input into pattern space
h                                    # save a copy of it in the hold buffer
s/(.*?78)(.*?5)(.*)/\2/S             # isolate the part to substitute
s/./X/g                              # replace non-newlines with X
s/^/@/                               # Put an @ as marker before the X's.
x                                    # Swap hold buffer and pattern space
G                                    # append hold buffer (now the X's) to
                                     # the pattern space. The PS now contains
                                     # the input followed by an @ followed by
                                     # the X's.
s/(.*?78)(.*?5)(.*)\n@(.*)/\1\4\3/S  # Use the @ marker (that we know to be
                                     # the last @ in the PS) to isolate the
                                     # X's and the original regex to isolate
                                     # the part we want to replace, then
                                     # reassemble.
```

As you can see, this is about as messy in ssed as it would be in sed, so I still suggest that it might be saner to use Perl:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/(?<=78)(.*?5)/$1=~s{[^\n]}{X}gr/se' << EOF
> (123) 456-7890
> (212) 567-9050
> EOF
(123) 456-78XX
XXXXXXX67-9050
```

Here, the `-0777` option puts perl into slurp mode, which makes it read the whole input in one go rather than linewise, and the code is a simple substitution, where

- `(?<=78)` is a lookbehind expression that matches an empty string if it is preceded by `78`
- `/e` enables us to use a perl expression in the replacement clause of `s///`, and
- `$1=~s{[^\n]}{X}gr` takes the first capture and replaces all non-newline charaters in it with `X`, yielding the result of the substitution. This is then substituted into the string where `(.*?5)` was matched.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Unfortunately, my question was edited after I posted it. I am using super-sed (ssed) not sed.  This version of sed has perl's regex built in.  I am specifically trying to figure out how to use its /S option or  the inline variant (?s).  (see https://launchpad.net/ssed/ for details of usage)

Comment: Oh, okay. Doesn't look too different from sed; at least I don't see a way to get around the hold buffer shuffle for this. I hacked something together (updated answer), but I still think this is beyond the scope of either sed or ssed. Is this for production code or a learning exercise?

Comment: purely a learning exercise for me. I didn't know about ssed and its optional switches look interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Noooo!!!! It's bad enough people are using sed for all sorts of wacky machinations but now there's super-sed for even more crazy rune combinations???

You don't tell us what sseds `/S` command does so I'm guessing it's for doing substitutions across multi-line blocks but sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all, and you should forget you ever heard about super-sed. For anything interesting related to manipulating text you should just use awk, e.g. with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ printf "(123) 456-7890\n(212) 567-9050\n" |
awk -v RS='78[^5]*5' -v ORS= '{print $0 gensub(/[^\n]/,"X","g",RT)}'
(123) 456-XXXX
XXXXXXX67-9050
```

or if you didn't want the `78` to be replaced:

```
$ printf "(123) 456-7890\n(212) 567-9050\n" |
awk -v RS='78[^5]*5' -v ORS= '{print $0 substr(RT,1,2) gensub(/[^\n]/,"X","g",substr(RT,3))}'
(123) 456-78XX
XXXXXXX67-9050
```

or:

```
$ printf "(123) 456-7890\n(212) 567-9050\n" |
awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= 'match($0,/(.*78)([^5]*5)(.*)/,a){print a[1] gensub(/[^\n]/,"X","g",a[2]) a[3]}'
(123) 456-78XX
XXXXXXX67-9050
```

and if you don't like that for some reason then just use perl, it's got to be every bit as readily available as ssed, probably more so!

Comment: I thought super-sed might have actually fulfilled the promise of slurping up the entire string if its perl regex option was turned on and the /S used. I wished for multiline edits as nice and easy as: ssed -R s/regex/replace/S. But no, it demands using pattern spaces, copies to the hold buffer, and an AI intellect to make it work, which is too byzantine for me.  Yes, your counterpoint awk example is simple enough to use comfortably.

Comment: GNU sed supports multi-line edits with it's `-z` option if that's all you're looking for but what's the point when you can just use awk for far better performance, clarity, portability, etc., etc.